# Recycle Bin for Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, delete

I have an Samsung S5 running Lollipop v5.  Does Lollipop have a concept of a "Recycling Bin" where deleted files go?  Or is a file/picture really deleted when I delete it?

Comment: The whole Android lineup (and Linux as well) does not feature a *Recycling Bin* concept. Developers are free to add this feature but as long as it's not mandatory in AOSP (Android Open Source Project), developers are not forced to add such a feature. Depending on the app you use, you may be able to hit a small `undo` button after you have deleted a file, memo etc. but this is application design only  and many apps do not feature this as well.

Comment: I was just deleting files using the "My Files" application that came with the S5.  And deleting pictures out of the "Gallery".  I then found out that I didn't back them up.  So I was wondering if there was any where else to "recover" them.

Comment: Windows OS has the recycle bin concept embedded in Windows Explorer and is not global in Windows OS too. Same goes for some GNU/Linux. In Android, as `GiantTree` said, it all comes down to the developer of the app. Some File Manger features Recycle Bin while others do not. As for you data-recovery case, have a look at questions tagged as [tag:data-recovery]. You probably would get the answer.

Comment: And your question seems to me as an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/286110). Consider an overhaul ([edit]) of it.

Comment: I would disagree that it's an XY problem since I don't have a solution.  I was just curious if there was a "reycling bin" feature in the default file explorer app "My Files" that came with the phone.  But thanks for your suggestion.